# UTC offset to local time conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I have a class where I format the dates to local time with utcoffset millis.

I am in a strange situation where the dates always formatted to UTC rather than to local time.

The timestamps or dates I am getting out the below method is always in UTC. How should I convert to local time with UTC offset millis.

```
public Object[] format(ReportContext context) {
        Map<String, String> queryParams = context.getQueryParams();

        DateRange dateRange = queryParams.containsKey(DATE_RANGE) ?
                DateRange.getDateRange(queryParams.get(DATE_RANGE)) :
                DateRange.LAST_24_HOURS;
        String messageKey = MESSAGE_KEY + dateRange.getRestParam();
        Object args[];
        Locale locale = context.getLocale();
        DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(19800000);
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterWithZone = dateFormatter.withZone(dateTimeZone);

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = parseParam(queryParams, START_TIME);
        String startDate = dateFormatterWithZone.print(startDateTime);

        if (dateRange == DateRange.TODAY || dateRange == DateRange.YESTERDAY) {
            args = new Object[]{startDate};
        } else {
            LocalDateTime endDateTime = parseParam(queryParams, END_TIME);

            if (dateRange == DateRange.LAST_24_HOURS) {
                DateTimeFormatter timeFormatterWithZone = timeFormatter.withZone(dateTimeZone);
                String startTime = timeFormatterWithZone.print(startDateTime);
                String endDate = dateFormatterWithZone.print(endDateTime);
                String endTime = timeFormatterWithZone.print(endDateTime);
                args = new Object[] {startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime};
                System.out.println("UTC time" + startDate + " " + startTime + " " + endDate + " " + endTime);
            } else if (dateRange == DateRange.LAST_HOUR) {
                DateTimeFormatter timeFormatterWithZone = timeFormatter.withZone(dateTimeZone);
                String startTime = timeFormatterWithZone.print(startDateTime);
                String endTime = timeFormatterWithZone.print(endDateTime);
                args = new Object[] {startDate, startTime, endTime};
            } else {
                String endDate = dateFormatterWithZone.print(endDateTime);
                args = new Object[] {startDate, endDate};
            }
        }

        return ars;
    }
```

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` does have *any* time zone, so the time zone of the formatter is meaningless, because without a time zone to begin with, the value cannot be converted to another time zone. What time zone did you expect the value coming back from `parseParam()` to have? What time zone do you want to convert it to? Edit and clarify your question, and please change your code to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens when DateTimeZone have some milliseconds let say UTC+5:30? I am surprised irrespective of supplied offset it always returns the date in UTC.

Comment: Since the input date **doesn't have a time zone**, how can the system *change* the time of day to a different time zone of +5:30 hours? Change from *what*?

Answer (score 2):

A `LocalDateTime` represents a date (day, month and year) and a time (hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds), without any notion of timezone. If I create this:

```
// March 8th 2018, at 10 AM (no timezone)
LocalDateTime startDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2018, 3, 8, 10, 0);
```

The `startDateTime` variable represents **"March 8th 2018, at 10 AM"**, but without a timezone, so it could be March 8th 2018, at 10 AM anywhere (or nowhere in particular, it doesn't matter). If you format this date, it doesn't matter what timezone you set in the formatter, it won't affect the output, because a `LocalDateTime` has no notion of timezone and won't be affected by it.

If you want to represent this date and time in a specific place (a geographic region, AKA a timezone), you must provide a `DateTimeZone` (the object that represents a timezone) and convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
DateTime dt = startDateTime.toDateTime(zone);
```

Note that I used the name `Asia/Kolkata` instead of a fixed numerical value for the offset. That's because timezones can change at anytime - politicians might decide to change the country's offset "because reasons" - so using a proper timezone name (and [keeping your timezone data updated](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html)) makes your code more reliable and future-proof.

This code makes `dt` equals to **"March 8th 2018, at 10 AM in Asia/Kolkata timezone"**. Now it's not a local date/time anymore: it represents a date and time in a specific location (represented by the timezone).

### Conversion between timezones

If your results are wrong, you must know in what timezone the `LocalDateTime` refers to, and then convert to the timezone you want.

Example: if I know that the `LocalDateTime` is in UTC and I want to convert it to "Asia/Kolkata", what should I do?

First, I convert the `LocalDateTime` to UTC:

```
// LocalDateTime is in UTC
DateTime utcDateTime = startDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Then, I convert this `utcDateTime` to the timezone I want:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
// convert utcDateTime to Asia/Kolkata timezone
DateTime kolkataDateTime = utcDateTime.withZone(zone);
```

`kolkataDateTime` will be equivalent to **"March 8th 2018, at 3:30 PM in Asia/Kolkata"** (because 10 AM in UTC is equivalent to 3:30 PM in `Asia/Kolkata` timezone).